# Git repository is not recognized unless VSCode is opened as administrator

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-for-windows

I have git installed, according to the CLI, it's version '2.36.0.windows.1'.
I have the latest VSCode, version '1.69.1 (user setup)'.
I am on Windows 10 Home, version '21H2 (build 19044)'.

I have a folder which contains my project and a .git subfolder.
Everything works as intended, if I run VSCode as an administrator.
If not, the git repository is not initialized and changes are not tracked.

This is not a huge deal, but i'd actually like to *not* have to run as administrator.
As far as I can tell the folder (single folder workspace) is trusted, so that shouldn't be it either.

Is there something I am missing, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running `git status` it said that the repository was owned by someone else and that it was not trusted.
It also suggests a command to fix that.
After running this command and restarting vscode, I had my repository as non administrator, so everything was working.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that your files are not Writable / Executable as your normal users, and those permissions are restricted to Administrators. You can solve this by right clicking on your folder in explorer -> properties -> security -> clicking on your user name -> edit -> full control .